# How to display images found on a Website with Java Primefaces <graphic image>

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I 
I am trying to display a group of Images from a website with Primeface Galleria.
I am trying to use the URLs to display the images
This is my xhtml code:

```
 <p:galleria id= "ISSimage" style="position : absolute; left:50px; top:400px" value="#{con.images}" var="image" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313" showCaption="true">
<p:graphicImage url="https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/sseop/images/ESC/small/ISS030/#{image}" alt="Image Description for #{image}" title="#{image}"/>
```

And this is my managed bean:

```
ArrayList images;
public void init() {
    images = new ArrayList<String>();
    images.add("ISS030-E-167972.JPG");
    images.add("ISS030-E-167972.JPG");

}

public List<String> getImages() {
return images;
}
```

So typically for example i would want to display the image:
https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/DatabaseImages/ESC/small/ISS030/ISS030-E-167972.JPG

But it comes up blank. Is this because of a problem with the code or the web.xml file or something else and if so how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your url in

```
<p:graphicImage url="https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/sseop/images/ESC/small/ISS030/#{image}" alt="Image Description for #{image}" title="#{image}"/>
```

is wrong.

Try:

```
<p:graphicImage url="https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/DatabaseImages/ESC/small/ISS030/#{image}" alt="Image Description for #{image}" title="#{image}"/>
```